# Laravel : hasOne Eloquent Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have a **transactions** table, which `hasOne` **site** and `hasOne` **accounthead**. But the **site** does not necessarily require to be bound to any transaction and the **accounthead**  can also stand alone without being bound to any **transaction**.

Basically the **Site** and **AccountHead** does not necessarily `belongsTo` **Transaction**.

How can I represent this scenario using eloquent relationships.

Am I missing anything I need to do in my **Site** and **AccountHead** Model?

Here's what I have already done:

**My transaction model:**

```
    class Transaction extends Model
{
  public function site()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Site');
    }
    public function accounthead()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\AccountHead');
    }
}
```

**My Site Model**

```
    class Site extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'location',
        'description'
    ];
}
```

**My AccountHead Model**

```
class AccountHead extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'slug',
        'accountname'
        ];
}
```

I need to be able to display the site and the accounthead for every transactions in my view.

**In my view:**

```
 @forelse($transactions as $transaction)
     <td>{{str_limit($transaction->accounthead,47)}}</td>
     <td>{{str_limit($transaction->site,47)}}</td>
   @endforelse
```

Comment: Could you update your question with your Site and AccountHead models?

Comment: Am I missing any columns that links the Site and AccountHead with the transactions table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved.**

It wasn't actually a one on one relationship, but was a `hasMany` relationship between a **Site** and **Transaction** and a **AccountHead** and **Transaction**.

**My new Site model looks like:**

```
class Site extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'location',
        'description'
    ];

 public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction','site_id');
    }
}
```

**My new AccountHead Model Looks like:**

```
class AccountHead extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'slug',
        'accountname'
        ];

public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction','accounthead_id');
    }
}
```

**And my new Transaction model looks like:**

```
    class Transaction extends Model
{
  public function site()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Site','id');
    }
    public function accounthead()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\AccountHead','id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, both tables need a `transation_id` field to add the transation record id. This can be `nullable()` and should be `unique()` to make sure that no other record has the same `transation_id`.

```
...
$table->integer('transation_id')->nullable()->unique();
...
```

In your view, you need to specify data you want from the relation. E.g.

```
<td>{{str_limit($transaction->accounthead->accountname,47)}}</td>
<td>{{str_limit($transaction->site->name,47)}}</td>
```

accountname/name being the field you want returned to the view.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. But now it's throwing 'trying to get property of non-object error'.  I am guessing this is because the transaction_id are all Null in the site and accounthead table. And the query $transaction->accounthead is not returning an object. How can I tackle this?